# Phoenix channel accept base64 png raw

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to send stream of **Base64 PNG images** (generated from capturing webcam) to Phoenix channel.

As far as I know, **handle_in** method in Channel only receives json string, so what I do currently is sending it using:

**channel.push("stream:video", JSON.stringify(data))**

Like below snippet:

```
var delay = 100
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") > -1) {
    delay = 40
    console.info(">>> using chrome")
} else {
    console.info(">>> using non chrome!")
}
let canvasContext = null
let camVideo = document.getElementById("cam-video")
let camCanvas = document.getElementById("cam-canvas")

let onSucceed = (stream) => {
    camVideo.srcObject = stream

    setInterval(() => {
        canvasContext.drawImage(camVideo, 0, 0, 240, 120)
        let data = camCanvas.toDataURL("image/png")

        // This is where I push Base64 image as string
        // I don't like this :P
        channel.push("stream:video", JSON.stringify(data))
    }, delay)
}

let onFailed = (error) => {
    console.error(error)
}

if (camVideo && camCanvas) {
    canvasContext = camCanvas.getContext("2d")

    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia 
    || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia 
    || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, onSucceed, onFailed)
}
```

So far using the above code, I can see a stream of Base64 string representation flowing to my channel (from server-side console log).

I do not fancy this, since I prefer if anyway I can tweak Phoenix channel be able to receives RAW Base64 binary stream.

I checked this [article](https://nerds.stoiximan.gr/2016/11/23/binary-data-over-phoenix-sockets/) but it seems to only enable server-side binary push to browser.

Is there anyway I can tweak **handle_in** to receives binary???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can upload binary into Phoenix's channel, but you have to remember that the message provided to `handle_in/3` must be a [map](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#c:handle_in/3), but this map can contain a binary in it.

You can check my [artitle](https://medium.com/@_pat_nowak_/file-upload-from-phoenix-channels-to-amazon-s3-29bc203678f9) about uploading files using Channels, where params contain filename and binary of the file.